# Storing XML values as a list using ClosedXML package

Tags: c#, arraylist, closedxml

I'm using the C# CLosedXML package to acquire XML data values and place them into a list. From what I found online, the only example of storing the values into an array in a list is as shown below.

```
var dataList = new List<string[]>()
{
    table.DataRange.Rows().Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("Story").GetString()).ToArray(),
    table.DataRange.Rows().Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("Level").GetString()).ToArray(),
    table.DataRange.Rows().Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("Combo").GetString()).ToArray(),
    table.DataRange.Rows().Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("Location").GetString()).ToArray(),
    table.DataRange.Rows().Select(tableRow => tableRow.Field("Asset").GetString()).ToArray(),
}
```

I have tried to print the details out in a console to visualize if the data was correctly stored in the list array which I've created. However, the `dataList` count is 5. Is it caused by the array size and is there a better way of coding this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < totalRows; j++)//totalRows more than 10
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Column {0} details: {1}", i+1, dataList[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly initializing the `dataList` variable as a list of 5 elements, each of which is an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you Francois.

I have trouble with the code as the additional data in each element cant be stored of more than 5. I believe its due to this error that I am getting _System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'_. 

In my excel file, I have more than 10 additional data which needs to be stored in the array. Could you advise where I went wrong with the script and how I can include the additional data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach like:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (string[] item in dataList)       
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Column {0} details: {1}", index+1, item[i]);
   }
        index++;
}
```